# Column data securely open for users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, development, asp.net

We had one secured list on SharePoint 2013. Under list different column exist. Particular one column(column name as "Internal data\link") we had more secured data (or) links exist. Our requirement is when new user access on list and when he\she click on item for seeing data.

Now requirement, particular column data need display when user exist on particular AD group, if not column data wont display to user for list item. Could anyone please suggest how to achieve on this request.

Answer (score 1):

There is no column level permission in sharepoint.

To achieve your requirement, you could use lookup column to achieve this:

> 1.Create a list to store the particular column data and make users in particular group can access the list.
>
> 2.In your secured list, create a lookup column to pull data from that list.Thus, only users in particular group will see the data in this
>   column.

Comment: Can we achieved by custom code?

Comment: As stated by Michael this is not supported in Sharepoint, With custom code anything is possible. But you need to think where you will store the data (as no longer you can store it list) so you need to think carefully about architecture of the solution.